# How can I start an RTC build via the command line?

Tags: clearcase, rtc

The build definition is created but in order to automate the build process I need to start the build via the command line.
How is this done ? Reading the doc on the scm command line client this does'nt seem to be described :

http://pic.dhe.ibm.com/infocenter/rtc/v1r0m0/index.jsp?topic=%2Fcom.ibm.team.scm.doc%2Ftopics%2Fc_scm_cli.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think `scm` is involved at all for launching a build.

You check out the Java API: See "[Automated Build Output Management Using the Plain Java Client Libraries](https://jazz.net/library/article/807)".

Or, you can use the [JB Toolkit](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.jazz.install.doc/topics/t_install_build_toolkit.html), and use a task like [`requestTeamBuild`](https://jazz.net/help-dev/clm/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.team.build.doc/topics/r_requestBuild.html):

> The `requestTeamBuild` task requests a build by using a specified build definition.
>   There must be an active engine that supports the build definition in order for the request to succeed.